# java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: com/trivago/cluecumber/engine/exceptions/CluecumberException

Tags: karate

I get the below error when I try to generate cluecumber report in Karate framework
java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: com/trivago/cluecumber/engine/exceptions/CluecumberException has been compiled by a more recent version of Java Runtime (class file version 55.0), this version of the Java Runtime only recognizes class file versions up to 52.0

Tried same coding in different machine and it worked. The Java version is same in both the system it's 1.8.0_341 but not sure why the report is successfully generate in one machine and not in another. Mainly the error is seen on the line import com.trivago.cluecumber.engine.exceptions.CluecumberException

Can someone help me with the working runner class code for an alternate way without using the above import

Comment: sounds like cluecumber is not compiled for java 8. you can try moving to java 11 (which you need to do soon anyway) and try. note that karate has 1.4.0.RC3 available

Answer (score 1):

Yes, Cluecumber requires Java 11 (https://github.com/trivago/cluecumber#building). Karate is also compatible with Java 11 and above as Peter said.

Comment: Thank you so much for the response . But in the machine its working has java 1.8.0_341 which is java8

Comment: @CucumberOptions(
     plugin = {"json:target/cucumber-report/cucumber.json"}
 )
public class TestRunner {
 

 @Test
 public void testParallel() throws CluecumberException
{
        Results results = Runner.path("classpath:report/clue.feature")
                .outputCucumberJson(true)
                .parallel(1);
        
    


     new CluecumberCore.Builder()
         .setCustomPageTitle("My cool report")
         .build()
         .generateReports(
             "target/karate-reports",
             "target/cluecumber-reports");
 
   
 }
Above is in runner file

Comment: Error seen due to line import com.trivago.cluecumber.engine.exceptions.CluecumberException; upon removing error is seen . Any alternative for the above for the report to work please

Comment: This seems to be mixing up Cucumber and Karate code. Are you using Cucumber or Karate? Because for Karate you don't specify CucumberOptions.